# Script no codifica a utf8

Tags: php, javascript, utf-8, urlencoding

Estoy tratando de enviar un parámetro por url desde javascript, y ese parámetro tiene tildes. Intento codificar a utf8 y luego codifico la url pero al parecer, no lo hace como debería (disculpen la necedad pero evitar tildes no es opción).

```
echo "<script>";
echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
echo "$('#filtrobusqueda').on('keyup', function() {";
echo "var palabra = document.getElementById('buscarpalabra').value;";
//echo "palabra = utf8_encode(palabra);"
//echo "palabra = encodeURI(palabra)";
$dato = "palabra";
echo    "$('#mostrar').load('mostrar.php?parametro='+". (urldecode(utf8_encode($dato))).");";

echo   "});";
echo "});";
echo "</script>";
```

Ya intenté con los que están comentados y no hace nada; intenté codificar con las funciones de php (urldecode y utf8_encode) pero tampoco lo reconoce.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo sin necesidad de tener que quitarle las tildes con otra función?

Comment: ¿Qué entrada y salidas tienes?

Comment: iconv(formatoOrigen, formatoDestino, $cadena), esta es una funcion de php que permite convertir de una codificacion de caracteres a otra. Para saber que codificación de Origen tiene tu cadena de texto puedes usar... mb_detect_encoding($cadena)

Comment: Entrada: ión; Salida: i?n

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo el mismo problema con un campo que tiene el símbolo "%", y lo envío con la función **urlencode()**.

Ejemplo:

```
<a target="_blank" href="MostrarQuery.php?variable1='.$ciclo.'&variable2='.urlencode($fila['remark']).'">
```